# cp -a is preserving ownership, from non-root user

Tags: linux, suse, cp

When I invoke `cp -a 1 2` from a non-root user, the ownership is being preserved, despite the fact that file `1` belongs to another user. My understanding was this shouldn't be possible.

What is going on?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure the `cp` binary doesn't have the *setuid* bit set...

```
$ ls -l /bin/cp /tmp/badcp1
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 103K Jul  1 11:59 /bin/cp
-rwsr-xr-x 1 root root 103K Jul  1 11:59 /tmp/badcp1
   ^
```

...and that it doesn't have any special capabilities assigned:

```
$ getcap /tmp/badcp2 
/tmp/badcp2 = cap_chown,cap_fowner+eip
```

If either is true, [this question](https://serverfault.com/questions/218005/my-servers-been-hacked-emergency) is a good start.

Comment: No to both cases.

Comment: Interesting. Can you successfully run `chown` (either the command or the programming function) on a file in the target filesystem? What type *is* the target filesystem? Are you sure that your uid is not 0?

Comment: @Matt: also, even if you don't have getcap, the OS feature is still there. An attacker may have brought their own copy of libcap2-bin. A good test is `cat /bin/cp > /tmp/cp; chmod +x /tmp/cp`, then try to use the /tmp/cp -a command to copy files and see if the strange behavior persists.